# Math solver with steps

Tags: math, symbolic-math, solver

I have a very hard time with math yet I always seem to find myself in ever increasingly difficult math courses. Over the years I have amassed a small 'fortune' of various scripts and programs. They are written in a variety of languages, from C to Java to Python and even a few in Lisp (I like to fool around with different languages). These are great for getting fast answers or checking my homework, but not so great for showing how those answers were gotten. My question is how would I go about adding a 'solver' aspect to these various programs? It doesn't need to be language specific, but just a concept or maybe a specific word or definition would be of immense help. I basically want to do a Wolfram Alpha type program, where you punch in the problem and it shows a step by step solution. I have spent the last couple of days researching this, but I am always redirected towards an app or, frustratingly, to Wolfram Alpha itself. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What categories of math are you talking about?

There does not seem to be a universal math solving program, what you mentioned sounds to me like the concept of a complicated math system(like MatLab).

And for, I think, a large scale of mathematical problems, the algorithms for computer programs to solve them differ from our ways to solve them.

Rather than a universal algorithm to achieve your goal, I think you can divide your problem into pieces, and achieve them with different sets of programs, there is a thesis [Symbolic Integration by Joel Moses](https://books.google.com/books/about/Symbolic_Integration.html?id=lkVAAQAAIAAJ), the first chapters give a good view of how to divide a math problem into programmable cases(in the example of solving quadratic equations), and the last hundred pages is a set of algorithms for solving irrational integration, interpreted in LISP.